# Adjusting TableRow Height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got a TableLayout, which fills a half of device's screen width. And I want to adjust it's TableRows height, depending on a size of a text, which I place in the TableRow.

What attribute should I use to do it in my XML description, because `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` doesn't help me?

Comment: can you pls copy the code and ur problem where u getting

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually I found dessision 5 minutes ago. I used stretchColumn and shrinkColumn properties of TableLayout)))

Comment: Please answer your own question as a separate entry and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by using [`android:stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns) and [`android:shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns) XML-attributes of `TableLayout` class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should convert it from dps to pixels using the display factor formula.

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; 

int trHeight = (int) (30 * scale + 0.5f);
int trWidth = (int) (67 * scale + 0.5f); 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutpParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(trWidth, trHeight);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutpParams);
```